How to Completely Remove All Metadata from a PDF using iText in .NET
I manage sensitive PDF documents and need to ensure all metadata is stripped before they are shared with third parties. Currently, my process involves physically printing and scanning the documents to remove any metadata, ensuring only the visible content is retained. I'm looking to automate this process using the iText library in a .NET environment (VB.NET or C#).
I've experimented with the following methods from the PdfDocumentInfo class to clear metadata:
Dim info As PdfDocumentInfo = pdfDoc.GetDocumentInfo()
info.SetTitle(Nothing)
info.SetAuthor(Nothing)
info.SetSubject(Nothing)
info.SetKeywords(Nothing)
info.SetCreator(Nothing)
info.SetMoreInfo(Nothing)
info.RemoveCreationDate()
info.SetKeywords("")
info.SetTrapped(PdfName.AllOff)

Despite these efforts, I've found that:

The SetCreator(Nothing) method does not fully remove the creator information.
XMP metadata is still present in the document.

I am seeking advice on how to thoroughly remove all metadata, including XMP, from PDFs using iText in a .NET setting. What additional steps or methods should I consider to ensure no metadata remains?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

pdfDoc.GetCatalog().SetXmpMetadata(Nothing)
